# Could not find file 'C:\Users\UserName\Documents\TestUpload.xlsx'.

Tags: c#, model-view-controller, iis-8

I have struggling with this for a whil now,I cannot seem to understand what is wrong, I have specified a location in the application to save the file to server when user uplaods, but it doesnt work with the above error thrown. All works well on my local machine but as soon as I deploy to the server it has this issue, I am running the application under a specifc user in my domain, I have given that user access to the folder and all rights but the error still perssits. This is an MVC application deployed to IIS and uses Windows Authentication.

Please see code below.

```
 public ActionResult Upload(HttpPostedFileBase file)
    {

        List<CleanSupplierClaim> supplierClaimsData = new List<CleanSupplierClaim>();

        try
        {
            if (file.ContentLength > 0)
            {

                var fileName = Path.GetFileName(file.FileName);
                var targetPath = Server.MapPath(@"~/upload");

                file.SaveAs(Path.Combine(targetPath, fileName));
```

Comment: It's really unclear where the path in your title comes from. You do realise that you cannot acces the client's filesystem from a web application?

Comment: @CodeCaster What do you mean I cannot read user file system from a web application, that is the main objective of the application, to read a file on the users machine and upload it to the server so that the file can be processed. Please assist and advise how I can get this done.